# how to use trac_ik library?

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, trac-ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I am trying to use the new library trac_ik in order to improve efficiency of the inverse kinematic process but I am not sure how to do it. Does anyone find out a way to use it?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221450/how-to-use-trac_ik-library?/) by [tristancrs](https://answers.ros.org/users/20175/tristancrs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-11-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-24**:
Can you clarify a bit? What is it that you actually want to do with it?

**Comment by [tristancrs](https://answers.ros.org/users/20175/tristancrs/) on 2015-11-24**:
right, instead of using KDL's ik, I'd like to use trac_ik. So basically, I received a position and orientation from an haptic device, and I want to process the inverse kinematic in order to get angular position of my robot arm and finally send the arm to this position. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the API is pretty straightforward given the README for the library.

https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/src/HEAD/trac_ik_lib/

There is a constructor and a CartToJnt() method that are both provided with the typical use case above.

If you are using MoveIt!, then you don't call TRAC-IK directly, you just ask MoveIt! to use TRAC-IK instead of KDL.

https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/src/HEAD/trac_ik_kinematics_plugin/

---

Originally posted by [pbeeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/695/pbeeson/) with karma: 276 on 2015-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pbeeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/695/pbeeson/) on 2016-01-17**:
UPDATE: The latest version has a) an example program for how to use the stand alone library (non-MoveIt! plugin) and b) a constructor that takes the URDF location on the rosparam server (e.g., "/robot_description") and that base and tip link of the chains, making use easier for KDL novices.